# My subsite redirects do the homepage of the main site if the url has 'www'

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, multisite

how are you?

I have a wordpress multisite and my main page is http://www.chablau.com.br and a subsite ( http://chablau.com.br/blog ). if the subsite url is used with a 'www', it returns a 404 error.

If I change the subsite domain to www.chablau.com.br/blog, the url without the 'www' will send me to the main site homepage

```
eg.: `http://chablau.com.br/blog/` works fine

     `http://www.chablau.com.br/blog returns` a 404 error
```

Someone has any clue about what is happenning ? bellow it, you can find what is in my .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Abonti|aggregator|AhrefsBot|asterias|BDCbot|BLEXBot|BuiltBotTough|Bullseye|BunnySlippers|ca\-crawler|CCBot|Cegbfeieh|CheeseBot|CherryPicker|CopyRightCheck|cosmos|Crescent|discobot|DittoSpyder|DOC|DotBot|Download Ninja|EasouSpider|EmailCollector|EmailSiphon|EmailWolf|EroCrawler|Exabot|ExtractorPro|Fasterfox|FeedBooster|Foobot|Genieo|grub\-client|Harvest|hloader|httplib|HTTrack|humanlinks|ieautodiscovery|InfoNaviRobot|IstellaBot|Java/1\.|JennyBot|k2spider|Kenjin Spider|Keyword Density/0\.9|larbin|LexiBot|libWeb|libwww|LinkextractorPro|linko|LinkScan/8\.1a Unix|LinkWalker|LNSpiderguy|lwp\-trivial|magpie|Mata Hari|MaxPointCrawler|MegaIndex|Microsoft URL Control|MIIxpc|Mippin|Missigua Locator|Mister PiX|MJ12bot|moget|MSIECrawler|NetAnts|NICErsPRO|Niki\-Bot|NPBot|Nutch|Offline Explorer|Openfind|panscient\.com|PHP/5\.\{|ProPowerBot/2\.14|ProWebWalker|Python\-urllib|QueryN Metasearch|RepoMonkey|RMA|SemrushBot|SeznamBot|SISTRIX|sitecheck\.Internetseer\.com|SiteSnagger|SnapPreviewBot|Sogou|SpankBot|spanner|spbot|Spinn3r|suzuran|Szukacz/1\.4|Teleport|Telesoft|The Intraformant|TheNomad|TightTwatBot|Titan|toCrawl/UrlDispatcher|True_Robot|turingos|TurnitinBot|UbiCrawler|UnisterBot|URLy Warning|VCI|WBSearchBot|Web Downloader/6\.9|Web Image Collector|WebAuto|WebBandit|WebCopier|WebEnhancer|WebmasterWorldForumBot|WebReaper|WebSauger|Website Quester|Webster Pro|WebStripper|WebZip|Wotbox|wsr\-agent|WWW\-Collector\-E|Xenu|yandex|Zao|Zeus|ZyBORG|coccoc|Incutio|lmspider|memoryBot|SemrushBot|serf|Unknown|uptime files" bad_bot
Deny from env=bad_bot
# END Bad Bot Blocker
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue I think is your virtual host setup is using "domain chablau.com.br" however it should be "www.chablau.com.br" and then you add a rule in your htaccess that redirects non www to www will solve your issue

Comment: thanks your information worked, especially the .htaccess insight. if anyone is looking how to do that, check this link

http://dense13.com/blog/2008/02/27/redirecting-non-www-to-www-with-htaccess/